# Is there any syntax error because, as per my understanding, the query is perfect

Tags: mysql, ranking, database-partitioning

Please let me know if there is any syntax error because, as per my understanding, the query is perfect:

```
mysql> SELECT Cust_Id,Plan_Id FROM(SELECT Cust_Id,Plan_Id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_Id ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS RN FROM(SELECT Cust_Id,Plan_Id,COUNT(1) as cnt FROM customer GROUP BY (Cust_Id,Plan_Id))) WHERE RN =1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near '(PARTITION BY Cust_Id ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS RN FROM(SELECT Cust_Id,Plan_Id,COUNT'
at line 1
```

Comment: Clearly, you need to have a discussion with your DBMS (MySQL), because it disagrees with you about the perfection of your SQL.  On the whole, I suspect the DBMS is correct and your claims of perfection are exaggerated.  Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL SERVER syntax not mysql. Mysql doesn't have the row_number() over () construct

Comment: Apparently your understanding is incorrect. You should work on that, because understanding is important most of the time.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve and what result do you expect with some sample data and the structure of the tables involved in your query.

Comment: Table Name customer with schema i.e

Answer (score 1):

`MYSQL` does not support `ROW_NUMBER()`.

You have to rewrite your query as below

```
SELECT Cust_Id,Plan_Id 
FROM (
       SELECT Cust_Id,Plan_Id,
              @row_num := IF(@prev_value=T.Cust_Id,@row_num+1,1) AS RN,
              @prev_value := T.Cust_Id
       FROM (
           SELECT Cust_Id,Plan_Id,COUNT(1) as cnt 
           FROM customer 
           GROUP BY (Cust_Id,Plan_Id)
            ) T,
           (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
           (SELECT @prev_value := 0) y
      )S WHERE RN =1;
```